# More and less than equal signs automatically changed into a single character

Tags: shell, kali-linux

So I installed a fresh version of Kali linux and identified weird feature which prevents me from scripting properly in the Terminal Emulator.

First in my existing files, text like `grep -o -P '(?<=Here).*(?=string)'` now looks like (see broken `<=`):
[image]

And then in the terminal itself, if I put `<=` or `>=` between single or double quotes it becomes like that:
[image]
[image]
so  I can't even type script which has more or less than equal characters.

Any idea what is this and how to get rid of this 'beautifying' feature which breaks my terminal?

My shell:

```
/usr/bin/zsh
```

My Kali:

```
Linux unknown 5.10.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1kali1 (2021-02-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you try another terminal emulator or TTY?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk if I do Ctrl + ALT  + f1 to enter tty, there i can type normally. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Change the font of terminal emulator, it use ligatures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)

Comment: @user1880405: yes, I wanted to narrow down possible culprits - it's not shell issue, it's terminal emulator issue

Comment: @RomeoNinov, this was indeed font (Bitstream Vera Sans Mono). Interesting to have a default font in Kali which prevents you to to even type in terminal. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look for me like font which support [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). The simplest you can do is to change the font of terminal.